# how can I use the new compose 1.0.0-alpha09

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the project `build.gradle` file I declare the compose and kotlin version in buildscript:

```
ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha07'
    }
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
```

Under that version my app can compile and run as normal, but when I upgrade the compose version like that:

```
ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha09'
    }
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
```

And my build will always fail with a `Backend Internal error`
So if there is someone who migrate to alpha09 successfully can tell me how to migrate to it?

Comment: Did you add [Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha09](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#declaring_dependencies) free compiler args statement, especially `-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies` one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build.gradle(Project) you should have this:

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha09'
}
```

and in build.gradle(app) this:

```
composeOptions {
   kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
   kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.21'
}
```

in Android Studio make:

- Build > Clean Project

then:

- Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: Actually, I made it works after invalidating caches and restarting... But thanks anyway!